# Exception handling strategy in prism application

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, user-controls, prism

We have several modules in our application. I have a project with a group of custom user controls which is used in the modules. Note that this user controls are not injected to the modules instead it is used as a user cotrol in the XAML inline.

Now the user controls can throw exceptions when it is loaded. I would like to handle the exceptions at the module level. The idea is I have an eventaggregator injected to the module constructor and upon catching the exception I can fire an error event.

For example the mainview of the module is as follows

**XAML**

```
<inf:DockBase 
    x:Class="MainView" 
    xmlns:inf="clr-namespace:Infrastructure"
    xmlns:usercontrols="clr-namespace:UserControls;assembly=Myusercontrollib">

    <Grid>
        <!--some code here-->
        <usercontrols:CustomListControl source={Binding myList}/>
    </Grid>
</inf:DockBase>
```

**Code behind**

```
public MainView()           
{
    InitializeComponent();         
}

public MainView(MainViewViewModel viewmodel, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    :this()  
{
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;  
}
```

Where can I catch excpetions from the user control in the module level??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just shooting from the hip. Perhaps the simplest method to catch exceptions on initialization is to allow access to your event aggregator via a singleton and raise the event from the view.

Once your application has started up however, if you wish to handle unhandled exceptions on the UI thread without the application crashing, you can try the [Application.UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This lets you handle an exception in Silverlight or WPF and process it, then either cancel or continue to allow the exception to throw you out of the application.

*Disclaimer: All untested code, both in compilation and execution*

```
public class MyView : UserControl
{   
    public MyView()
    {
        // Hardly best practice, but it'll work
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch(Exception caught)
        {
            EventAggregatorService.Instance.GetEvent<XamlExceptionEvent>().Publish(/* ... */);
        }
    }
}

public class EventAggregatorService
{
    public IEventAggregator Instance { get { return _instance; } } 

    // NOTE: Must be called once in your bootstrapper to set the EA instance
    public static void SetEventAggregator(IEventAggregator instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }
}
```

Taking it a step further, if you can create a base viewmodel like this

```
// Base viewmodel type to handle errors
public abstract class ErrorViewModel
{
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    protected ErrorViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public void HandleInitializationException(object view, Exception caught)
    {
        // Publish event via _eventAggregator
    }
}
```

Where derived view models are defined like this

```
// Derived viewmodel type
public class DerivedViewModel : ErrorViewModel
{
    public DerivedViewModel (IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : base(eventAggregator)
    {
    }
}
```

You could apply the following method to your view as follows, by catching the exception and deferring error handling.

```
public class MyView : UserControl
{   
    private readonly Exception _ex;

    public MyView()
    {
        try { InitializeComponent(); } catch (Exception caught) { _ex = caught; } 
    }

    protected override OnDataContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_ex == null) return;

        var vm = view.DataContext as ErrorViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.HandleInitializationException(view, caught);
            return;
        }

        throw new Exception("Error occurred during View initialization", _ex);
    }
}
```

Ok its not neat and its not pretty, but again it'll work. Taking it a step further you may be able to create a base view type to factor out initialization too, however if you are inheriting multiple different base types then this won't help you. Alternatively a help class to defer initialization, calling the `Initializecomponent()` method via reflection.

Finally, the code for UnhandledException handling:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, 
        ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ExceptionObject is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // Inform the user
            EventAggregatorService.Instance.GetEvent<MyUnhandledExceptionEvent>().Publish(/* ... */);
            // Recover from the error
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
    }
}
```

Just some ideas. I'd be interested to hear if there is a defacto solution to this as I've often encountered this problem!

Best regards

Comment: I can see this solution will work when the user control is loading for the first time(InitializeComponent()). However, the user control can be modified by user action after it is loaded successfully, and hence result in an exception. I am struggling to find out how that situation can be solved. I am thinking in terms of an exception handler which will take care of specified exceptions from an inner object. However, I cannot see any possibility to do that in this situation.

Comment: @Jimmy have you considered Application.UnhandledException event?

Comment: Andrew, Application.UnhandledException can solve the problem, but it looks a bit wrong for a modular approach. Also, if I susbscribe to the event will it catch unhandled exceptions from other modules in the application?

Comment: @Jimmy It will catch unhandled exceptions thrown anywhere on the UI thread from any module. Unfortunately there is no way to catch an unhandled exception other than this, so a module specific solution cannot be done unless you manually insert try-catch blocks around all code you expect to throw

Comment: Andrew, thank you. Probably the mistake I am doing is trying to mix a custom user control which is not injected with prism module. I will make the user control a prism component and pass the event aggregator to it. So, instead of throwing an exception the user control will fire an Error event.

Comment: @Jimmy yes that'll do it. Alternatively use the `ErrorViewModel` approach above and cast your datacontext to ErrorViewModel at the point you wish to custom handle an exception. That way you don't need to inject IEventAggregator into View code and the view will work at runtime even if a viewmodel is not defined

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson I'm not sure about concurrency on this one. The eventaggregator looks async to me i.e you fire a weakevent but you don't know when it's handled, and it doesn't stop the main thread. Logging is about exactitude so this might not be the best idea.

Comment: @Baboon yes you're right, if the subscriber of EventAggregator event is a logger. In previous apps I've developed I've used a method similar to this (Unhandled Exception handler) to publish an event to the GUI to notify the user. Logging was done in-place at the point the exception was caught. If you have anything to add that could go in an answer please make one! I'd be interested to hear other people's opinions on exception handling and logging strategies in prism client apps. Regards,

Comment: I think your `public IEventAggregator Instance` property should be declared static. Later on you access i as if static: `EventAggregatorService.Instance`.